# Dynamically importing modules in Haskell

Tags: haskell, scotty

I'm building a Scotty-based application and I'm trying to import and add a list of dynamic middlewares contained in a directory.

I don't want to hard-code my list of middleware - but as of now I'm using a `Index.hs` which expose all the directory middlewares.

Let's say I have a `Main.hs`

```
import Controllers.Index (endpoints)
...

main :: IO ()
main = do
  port <- read <$> getEnv "PORT"
  scotty port $ do
         middleware logStdoutDev
         endpoints
```

Then in `Controllers/Index.hs`:

```
module Controllers.Index
( endpoints ) where

import Controllers.Order (order)
import Controllers.User (user)
...
import Web.Scotty (ScottyM)

endpoints :: ScottyM ()
endpoints = order >> user >> ...
```

Each `Controllers/*.hs` contains a middleware.

What would be the best way to get rid of `Controllers/Index.hs`?
Is there a way of importing all the modules from a directory and getting a list I can work with?

Comment: You can use cabal to generate the Controllers.Index module at configure time, probably.

Comment: You mean generating the `Index.hs` file from `Setup.hs`? That's pretty clever.
I suppose I am right in assuming there is nothing in Haskell which will let me import modules dynamically, then? (this ticket actually seems to confirm this: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/1475)

Comment: Yes, you cannot import modules dynamically. I think the priority on that ticket is quite low, so you shouldn't expect anything like that any time soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit late, but this package helps to generate the needed imports from the setup, as suggested in the comments:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/imports